# Tree view links in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

We have to design an interface for a scrum management system as a uni product. However, we are solely interested in the interface. There is zero marking for coding (and we have not in fact used any C#). All we need to do is link the forms (and even this isn't required).

To make the form more readable I have included a tree view. It looks like this:

```
All projects
  - Project 1
    - Product Backlog
    - Team
    - Sprints
      - Sprint Backlog 1
      - Sprint Backlog 2  

  - Project 2 etc
```

On my main interface page, I have linked to each Project, so you can select a project in the tree view and it will bring up a new form (on top of the previous one). This uses the following code:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Node.Text)
        {
            case "Project 1":
                var newForm = new ProjectInterface();
                newForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
                break;

            etc
        }
    }
```

This all works okay on the main interface page. However, when I open the new form up to view Project 1, none of the links in the tree view actually work. For example, if I'm viewing Project 1 and wish to view Project 2, the following code (I thought!) should work:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Node.Text)
        {
            case "Project 2":
                var newForm = new ProjectInterface2();
                newForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Additionally, please bear in mind the way we are doing this has been set by the lecturer (we are also learning to use Subversion at the same time). Therefore, don't worry about pointing out more efficient ways to do it, just how to link the forms together! Thanks

Comment: Did you tried debugging it? Did the breakpoint actually reached in case "Project 2":

Comment: It seems to be reaching it. It just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try replacing newForm.Show() with newForm.ShowDialog()

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately. Once I get through first form onto the "Project 1" form, the links die. No idea why.

Comment: Ok. Where is the code residing that has case "Project 2" in it? Is it in the form ProjectInterface() or the main form. I mean to ask, do you have only one tree list on main form? or have tree list on all forms?

Comment: I have a tree list on all forms. Originally, we wanted to have one form with multiple panels, but as we are working through Subversion this won't work.

Comment: To create the ProjectInterface form, I copied the Interface form, renamed it and added in the rest of the necessary code. Is it likely I have created an object of the tree in the original Interface form and then not changed it in the new form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20629/discussion-between-azhar-khorasany-and-andrew-martin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the main form treelist1 code in the designer and compare it with the copied form designer code, you will notice that this line is missing this.treeView1.AfterSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.treeView1_AfterSelect);

Add this to the new copied form designer and it should work.